# Sent html email using gmail API, it appears in "chinese" on apple mail client

Tags: node.js, html-email, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am sending emails using the Gmail NodeJS API using these code snippet (leaving auth out of it)

```
        const headers: any = {
            'To': event.to,
            'Subject': event.subject,
            "Content-Type": "text/html; charset='UTF-8'",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "base64"
        }
        let email = ''
        for (let header in headers) {
            email += header += ": " + headers[header] + "\r\n";
        }

        email += "\r\n" + event.body;
        
        const theMessage = {
            'userId': "me",
            'resource': {
                'raw': _btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(email))).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
            }
        }

        const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            webAppClientId, this.clientSecret, "https://docs-n-data......");
        const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth})
        gmail.users.messages.send(theMessage)
```

The email renders correctly on most email clients, except the ios email client on iphone.  It looks like "chinese" in that client.  Please see the attached image, following the suggestion by @DalmTo:

[image]

Some articles on the web hint that this might be due to the email being interpreted as UTF-16 instead of UTF-8, but none of them explain what to do.

I am trying to state that the encoding is UTF-8 in the above code, so am not sure whats wrong.  Please help, thanks!

**Update** Maybe the content of the email body is important.  The content comes from this template:

```
const emailBody = `<html>
<body>
<p>Hi {{Customer.First name}},</p>
<p>Your booking is confirmed for {{Date}} at {{Time}} and we have charged you the
    amount of &pound;{{Paid}}</p>
<p>Your booking reference is {{Booking number}}.</p>
<p>Use this link to <a href="https://google.com">cancel your booking</a>, should you wish to.</p>
<p>Use this link to <a href="https://google.com">amend your booking</a>, should you wish to.</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

**Update 2** I changed the template for the email to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi {{Customer.First name}},</p>
<p>Your booking with The Smart Wash Ltd is confirmed for {{Date}} at {{Time}} and we have charged you the
    amount of &pound;{{Paid}}</p>
<p>Your booking reference is {{Booking number}}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I get this rendering on iphone mail client.  On the ipad mail client and gmail, it renders correctly:

[image]

When I view the same email in gmail, and "Show original", I see this:

[image]

Not sure who or what is putting the `text/plain` version in there, but including this detail in case it helps.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output you are getting.

Comment: Sending email in plain text over the user that is using the iphone mail client, it displays normally? The API could be working properly, however the mail client configuration is not allowing Rich text and not downloading the HTML format and forcing the special characters.

Answer (score 1):

I setted "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "8bit" and it worked for me!